# How do i change the visibility of multiply objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Currently I am struggling with the next problem.

I want to change the visibility of all array objects to hidden with a for loop when clicking on a button (terug). I have the following code, but this doesn't work:

```
var titel = $('#wiebenik'); 
var mijndiplomas = $('#mijndiplomas');
var mijnwerkervaring = $('#mijnwerkervaring');  
var mijntalen = $('#mijntalen');    
var mijnvaardigheden = $('#mijnvaardigheden');  
var mijntoekomst = $('#mijntoekomst');
var mijneigenschappen = $('#mijneigenschappen');    

var titels = [titel, mijndiplomas, mijnwerkervaring, mijntalen, 
     mijnvaardigheden, mijntoekomst, mijneigenschappen];

    var trgbtn = document.getElementById('terug');
    trgbtn.onclick = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < titels.length; i++){
        titels.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    };
```

Is there a possible way to change te visibility value of all objects to hidden?

Many thanks!

Comment: Why don't you put a class on each of those so you can `$('.please-invisible-me-when-clicked').css('visibility', 'hidden')`? Or go up to the parent (if possible) and hide it? This just seems like too much work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the following, you create jQuery objects of every element. Like this `var titel = $('#wiebenik');`. To hide this element you can use the jQuery function `hide` or `css`. Like the following `titel.hide()` or `titel.css("visibility", "hidden")`.

Or event better, select more elements with 1 selector. Just like in CSS. `$("#wiebenik, #mijndiplomas, #mijntalen").hide()`.

If you persist to use native, you can use a native selector like `document.getElementById("wiebenid")` or get the first object from the jQuery element `$("#wiebenid")[0]`, since jQuery objects are just Arrays with extra functions.

Finally, your loop is not correct, you have to use the index of the element in the array to hide it. (added `[i]`)

```
for (var i = 0; i < titels.length; i++){
    titels[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Note: `jQuery.hide()` and `visibility: hidden` are not synonymous, the latter maintains layout, the former collapses all spatial layout (as if it didn't exist anymore, rendering-wise). The former is also `display: none` under the "hood".